# Docker container can not open keystore

Tags: docker, spring-boot, dockerfile, keystore, resttemplate

I have a tomcat:8-jre8-slim base image to which I add my spring boot war with all the required env. variables. Some of them point to the location of the keystore but when the spring boot app starts the resttemplate can not open the keystore:

```
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/source/mykeystore.jks]
```

I checked the filesystem of the docker image and they are at the pointed location and the password is correct.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8-slim
ADD build /source
WORKDIR /source

RUN mkdir source
COPY certs/mykeystore.jks /source
COPY certs/client.p12 /source
RUN cd /source && chmod 777 * && ls

.......


ENV client.ssl.key-store=/source/client.p12
ENV client.ssl.key-store-password=password
ENV client.ssl.trust-store=/source/mykeystore.jks
ENV client.ssl.trust-store-password=password

.......

COPY build/libs/*.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps
```

Why is this happening and any suggestions for my problem?

Comment: Could you provide more output from build process? The Dockerfile looks good but the output might reveal other issues. Also - it might be something in between the ellipsed lines.

Comment: can you also privide the application.properties that uses those ENV vars?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough input from your post. I suspect `chmod 777 *` is not enough. Try putting `chmod 777 -R /source`

Comment: tried this, still the same error. Also, I don't think that output from running "docker build" is helpful in this case, since it just shows the contents of the folder (because I ran "ls") and the rest is a bunch of  "Removing intermediate container 958c20fb2c63
 ---> 8cee18dfe0f8
Step 42/43 : ENV spring.flyway.validate-on-migrate=true
" similar things

Comment: `ls` is not enough. Always provide `ls -al` or even `ls -alZ` on Selinux-based OSes or even `namei -l <path>` which shows all permissions and owners from `/` till the file/directory affected..

Comment: Another thing is - if you use volumes/mounts they supress underneath directory. That's why it's desirable to provide complete command line and Dockerfile.